# How To Store Polygon Coordinates (GeoJSON) as an array into a MongoDB Database Using NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, geometry, geojson

I am trying to store a Polygon into my MongoDB Database, using Mongoose. I have tried every alternative out there but I can't figure it out unfortunately. I found a way to store coordinates as a String, but not as a geoJSON array (Polygons).
The `territory` property of the `organization` object should be a `polygon` and should be stored in an array.
I am using `POSTMAN` for testing purposes, and below is a screenshot of my POST request of the coordinates:
  [image]

When I submit my post request, I get this error back:

[image]
Here is how the object is getting stored in the database, as a String instead of an array of points
[image]
I have tried multiple version of the code below and I either get the above response or another one stating that `cast to array failed for value...`.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong or how to get this working.

Below is my code.

**Organization.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var organizationSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
name:String,  
address:String,  
point:{type:[Number],index:'2d'},  
territory:{  
  type:{  
    type:String,  
    required:true,  
    enum:['Point','LineString','Polygon'],  
    default:'Point'  
  },  
  coordinates:[mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]    
}    
});  
organizationSchema.index({coordinates:'2dsphere'});
```

**API.js**

```
var Organization = require('./models/organization');
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
    apiRoutes.route('/organizations')
      .post(function(req,res,next){
          var organization = new Organization();
          var pointData = {
              latitude:req.body.latitude,
              longitude:req.body.longitude
          };
          var loc = req.body.coordinates;

          organization.name = req.body.name;
          organization.address = req.body.address;
          organization.latitude = req.body.latitude;
          organization.longitude = req.body.longitude;
          organization.point = [pointData.longitude,pointData.latitude];
          organization.territory = {
             coordinates: loc,
             type: req.body.type
          };
          //save the new organization and check for errors
          organization.save(function (err, organization) {
            if (err)
                return res.send(err)
            res.json({ 
                message: 'The Organization was successfully created!',
                Organization: organization 
            });
          });
     });
```

Comment: Do you still need the answer?

Comment: i still do. your answer is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I have created a repository on [github](https://github.com/SarasArya/Geofence-Node-Mongoose) to give an example on how to store polygon and circle coordinates in a NodeJS powered backend.
I could tell you where you went wrong but that might not solve your issue and you will be straddled with another one.
For starters
1. Your schema declaration is wrong. It should have a type and a coordinate element.
2. Longitude comes first and then the latitude while ordering the coordinates. This is mentioned in the docs

For more details, you can head to the repo run the code and understand for yourself. If you still find any issues. Please let me know via GitHub or here.

Comment: Can you post answer here please. you given github link is not working

Comment: Sure will do. Give me 24 hrs.